# How to add my local compiled OpenCV to Python path?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm using Windows 10 with python 3 installed. I downloaded the opencv 4 source code and compiled it from its cmake file successfully. I also run the install.vcproj to install it.

The install path is like this:

```
C:\OpenCV
  bin
  etc
  include
  sample
  x86
    vc15
      bin
      lib
```

Then I manually add `C:\OpenCV\x86\vc15\bin` to the environment variable of `path`, so that I can run the compiled c++ samples.

Now I want to run some python samples, in `C:\OpenCV\samples\python`, for example, the `opencv_version.py`, but I have a `ModuleNotFoundError` at this line of code:

```py
import cv2 as cv
```

It seems that my locally compile opencv can't be found by python.

I know that if I want to use the precompiled opencv, I just run `pip3 install opencv-python`, but now I don't want to use the precompiled version, I want to use my own compiled opencv for python.

Questions:

1. Do I need to change some cmake configurations during my build of opencv to enable its python binding?
2. How do I add my own opencv to the path of python, which path (in my case, which `C:\OpenCV` sub-folder) should be added?

Answer (score 0):

once you have compiled from source successfully using make, purge any other versions of opencv and just run make install.

Answer (score -1):

you have to add this opencv in python modules

There are several ways to add things to the PYTHONPATH.

Read http://docs.python.org/library/site.html

```
Set the PYTHONPATH environment variable prior to running your script.

You can do this python -m agent to run agent.py from your PYTHONPATH.

Create .pth files in your lib/site-packages directory.

Install your modules in lib/site-packages.
```

Comment: Do you know which path (in my case, which `C:\OpenCV` sub-folder) should be added?